# How to get values from "for" loop into dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe, selenium, beautifulsoup

I have a code that scraped soccer games. I have added values but I am unable to include in the dataframe.

How can I get the values `country` and `competition` in the dataframe for the url ?

(it would be better to get the country and competition for every match)

```
import os
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from tabulate import tabulate
from datetime import datetime
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs 

start = datetime.now()

browser = webdriver.Chrome()


class GameData:

    def __init__(self):
        self.date = []
        self.time = []
        self.game = []
        self.score = []
        self.home_odds = []
        self.draw_odds = []
        self.away_odds = []


def parse_data(url):
    browser.get(url)
    df = pd.read_html(browser.page_source, header=0)[0]
    time.sleep(3)
    html = browser.page_source
    soup = bs(html,"lxml")
    cont = soup.find('div', {'id':'wrap'})
    conti = cont.find('div', {'id':'col-content'})
    content = conti.find('table', {'class':'table-main'}, {'id':'tournamentTable'})
    main = content.find('th', {'class':'first2 tl'})
    count = main.findAll('a')
    country = count[1].text
    league = count[2].text
    game_data = GameData()
    game_date = None
    for row in df.itertuples():
        if not isinstance(row[1], str):
            continue
        elif ':' not in row[1]:
            game_date = row[1].split('-')[0]
            continue
        game_data.date.append(game_date)
        game_data.time.append(row[1])
        game_data.game.append(row[2])
        game_data.score.append(row[3])
        game_data.home_odds.append(row[4])
        game_data.draw_odds.append(row[5])
        game_data.away_odds.append(row[6])
    browser.quit()
    return game_data, country, league

# You can input as many URLs you want
urls = {
"https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/europe/champions-league/results/"
}

if __name__ == '__main__':

    results = None

    for url in urls:
        game_data, country, competition = parse_data(url)
        result = pd.DataFrame(game_data.__dict__)
        if results is None:
            results = result
        else:
            results = results.append(result, ignore_index=True)


print('The country is',country)
print('The competition is', competition)
print(tabulate(results.head(), headers='keys', tablefmt="github"))
end = datetime.now()
time_taken = end - start
print('Time taken to complete: ', time_taken)

result:

The country is  Europe
The competition is Champions League
|    | date        | time   | game                                 | score   |   home_odds |   draw_odds |   away_odds |
|----|-------------|--------|--------------------------------------|---------|-------------|-------------|-------------|
|  0 | 17 Mar 2021 | 20:00  | Bayern Munich - Lazio                | 2:1     |        1.35 |        6.02 |        7.53 |
|  1 | 17 Mar 2021 | 20:00  | Chelsea - Atl. Madrid                | 2:0     |        2.33 |        3.1  |        3.49 |
|  2 | 16 Mar 2021 | 20:00  | Manchester City - B. Monchengladbach | 2:0     |        1.28 |        6.25 |       10.17 |
|  3 | 16 Mar 2021 | 20:00  | Real Madrid - Atalanta               | 3:1     |        2.26 |        3.6  |        3.16 |
|  4 | 10 Mar 2021 | 20:00  | Liverpool - RB Leipzig               | 2:0     |        2.37 |        3.8  |        2.85 |
Time taken to complete:  0:00:15.875088
```

expected result:

```
     date    time       country competition                  game                                     score         home_odds   draw_odds   away_odds
--- --------    --------    --------    --------    --------------------------------------  ---------      ------------ -------------   ------------
0   17/03/2021   20:00      Europe  Champions League     Bayern Munich - Lazio                     2:01         1.35             6.02           7.53
1   17/03/2021   20:00      Europe  Champions League     Chelsea - Atl. Madrid                     2:00         2.33             3.1            3.49
2   16/03/2021   20:00      Europe  Champions League     Manchester City - B. Monchengladbach      2:00         1.28             6.25           10.17
3   16/03/2021   20:00      Europe  Champions League     Real Madrid - Atalanta                    3:01         2.26             3.6            3.16
4   10/03/2021   20:00      Europe  Champions League     Liverpool - RB Leipzig
```

I want to include the country and competition in the dataframe results

p.s. I felt "Improving my "for" loop" was a better title but the rules did not allow. Mods can delete this statement

Answer (score 0):

Just add it to the `result` dataframe within your loop prior to appending it to `results` dataframe:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    results = None

    for url in urls:
        game_data, country, competition = parse_data(url)
        result = pd.DataFrame(game_data.__dict__)
        result['country'] = country
        result['competition'] = competition
        if results is None:
            results = result
        else:
            results = results.append(result, ignore_index=True)
```